# Sending a password to sshfs inside a GUI front end

Tags: linux, frontend, sshfs

I am trying to make a front end for sshfs in Linux where the user connects with a key + password. I want to be able to send the password to ssh when it asks, then have sshfs stay running when the gui exits.

The Linux terminals are able to do this but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I tried this by creating a tty with the sshfs command and I see the password prompt but when I send it, ssh just quits. If I create a normal ssh connection this works fine. Maybe it is because sshfs spawns ssh?

I tried running with popen () with sshfs -o password_stdin option and sending the password by writing "password\n" to the file pointer returned with popen (). The password does not seem to make it to ssh. Tried with or without the ending '&'.

I tried the `system ()` function with the same -o password_stdin and using with or without the ending '&':

```
  echo password > sshfs -o password_stdin  ...       (sshfs won't start)
  echo password | sshfs -o password_stdin ...        (times out waiting for prompt)
  sshfs -o password_stdin ... <<< 'password'         (times out waiting for prompt)
```

Even when I try: `'echo password | sshfs -o password_stdin ...'` in a normal terminal it times out waiting for a password.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `sshpass` command.

Comment: Is that with the '-o ssh_command=sshpass' option on sshfs? When I try that I get a broken pipe

Comment: I think it would be something like `ssh_command='sshpass -ppassword ssh'` where you replace `password` with the actual password.

Comment: I noticed something odd. When I run the normal command with the system() function: "/usr/bin/sshfs ...", one system prompts me with a gui dialog, but on another computer it does not? Neither computer has ssh-askpass installed

Comment: The other may have the password saved in SSH agent.

Comment: I was wrong about the first pc. It did have ssh-askpass installed even though the package was not installed. Found it by looking at environment variable SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass. The 2nd pc didn't have it installed and there was no enviornment variable SSH_ASKPASS. Installed ssh-askpass package in second pc and it worked.

Comment: I still would like to know how to send the password to ssh when it asks like the Linux terminals such as konsole does it. Without using ssh-askpath. Any ideas?